# How to use DataTables with Laravel Vite?

Tags: jquery, datatables, vite, laravel-9, laravel-vite

I'm having trouble adding DataTables to my new Laravel 9.21 instance. But I'm getting an error in the console. What am I missing?

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

**bootstrap.js**

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = jquery;
window.$ = jquery;

import DataTable from 'datatables.net';
window.DataTable = DataTable;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick is `DataTable(window, window.$)`

The idea comes from the official doc of [datatables.net-bs5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables.net-bs5). The setup from `require( 'datatables.net-bs5' )( window, $ );`

My `app.js` looks like this

```
import "./bootstrap";
import "../sass/app.scss";

import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";

import jQuery from "jquery";
window.$ = jQuery;

import DataTable from "datatables.net-bs5";
DataTable(window, window.$);
```

I hope it gives you some hints.

Comment: DataTable($); worked

Comment: Dude, I love you. Hours wasted trying to figure this out but your solution worked.

Comment: You Rock!!!   Thank You!   This will help out so many users out there using both these technologies.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution to my problem.

**bootstrap.js**

```
import jQuery from "jquery";
window.$ = jQuery;

import DataTable from 'datatables.net';
window.DataTable = DataTable;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, just the simple thing worked.

```
import $ from "jquery";
window.$ = $

import DataTable from 'datatables.net';
window.DataTable = DataTable;
```

My versions : `Vite 4.0.4 and Laravel 9`

Answer (score 0):

first import DataTables CSS and JS in your application.

path: resources/js/app.js

```
import DataTable from 'admin-lte/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js';
window.DataTable = DataTable;
```

in blade file

```
 @push('scripts')
    <script type="module" >
      $(document).ready(function() {
           new DataTable('#table2', {} );
      });
     </script>
    @endpush
```